# Adding value to a json file dynamically from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `student.json` file which looks like this:

```
    {
      "nodes":[
        {"name":"Anup"},
        {"name":"Panwar"}
    ],

    "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":1}
         ]
    }
```

and I want to get user input values in my html page and append them to `student.json`.

Comment: So where is the issue?

Comment: you cannot append data to files with browser api

Comment: where in the file you want to input the values?

Answer (score 0):

You can add like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(txt);  //parse the JSON
data.employees.push({        //add the employee
    firstName:add fname, 
    lastName: add lname
});
txt = JSON.stringify(data);  //reserialize to JSON
```

Comment: That is not what OP has asked. Op needs to add data in the `.json` file instead of reading. Tell him how to save records in `.json` file.

Comment: _i want to get user input values in my html page and **append** //them to `student.json`_ check this.....;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in a web browser.. you can't write data directly to a file from a web browser.. This happens because browser should not have the permission to write files (unless the webpage is saved)

You can only access it through url

for this.. i recommend creating a server that would handle `Database` information, or change the content of file just like you ask (which i don't recommend if the file ends up being big data and would make the server take longer for reading and parsing data)